# SQL: Array of Tables

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm learning to use SQL Server Compact with my C# program, and I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

I want to have an array of tables. In my program the user creates data tables, each of which is to be stored in an SQL table. The tables are indexed by a unique string on the C# side of things (table "foo", table "bar", etc.). I can make a table that matches these strings to an integer ID, but I don't know how to make something like an array of tables for the index in the database.

My thought is I can convert the integer ID to a string ID, like turning "13" into "table_0013" and using that for the table name. But I thought maybe there was a better way.

So what do you usually do when you need an array of tables?

Comment: What, pray tell, is an "array of tables"?

Comment: If this was C# you would have "DataTable[] Tables" and refer to the tables as Tables[0], Tables[1], etc. I want to know the correct way to do this kind of thing in SQL

Comment: If you are going to dynamically create tables I think you mainly just want to ensure your SQL table names don't collide.
Right now I am working on a program that names new tables based on a $requested_name. It checks to see if such a table already exists. If not, it uses the $requested_name. If it does, it adds "_1", "_2", etc. to the end.